# Select file(image) for uploading during Nighwatch tests on CircleCI

Tags: javascript, selenium, docker, nightwatch.js, circleci

I'm working with Nightwatch.js tests, we have test runs on docker container in CircleCi.

I need to upload an image from the file system to my service during the Nightwatch test on CircleCi, have found this solution:

`.setValue('input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve('/home/My-PC/Desktop/img.png'))`

But it only works from local machine.
Does anyone know how to upload my file on CircleCi service and what path to it will be? Or maybe there are some workarounds? I thought about uploading of my file to Dropbox and downloading during test run, but I'm not sure how to implement this with Nightwatch and what path I will need to use to find downloaded file.

Comment: what about some publicly accessible file location like raw github or ftp and ad path in resolve. Just choose any publicly accessible path/url

Comment: SIMPLE, just use a publicly accessible resource, like the gentlemen above suggested, or, if you don't mind the overhead, add the resource to a `./assets` folder in your `/test` folder and submit it. Your build will always have the `/assets`, so just give it the path based on the current dirname: `./test/assets/img.png`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why publicly accessible file doesn't work in my case - I can only upload a file from file storage as this is the only option for nightwatch setValue.

I found the solution here - https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/custom-images/#creating-a-custom-image-manually

I have created own docker image with files I need and published it on Docker Hub. Then in the config file of CircleCi, I'm using this image.